# PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

When I try to run SQL scripts which have functions in them, the system throws an error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.`.

The task is to take bunch of sql files and execute them on DB. I use hibernate and postgres, here are the dependencies from POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

All the files are executed one after another in a loop. I begin transaction before starting the loop and commit it after the loop has ended. Text from each file is passed into `Query sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(script)` and after that I call `sqlQuery.executeUpdate()`. This is where it fails when encounters a script with function. It seems that only more complex functions fail, small functions pass OK

This, for example passes:

```
DO'
DECLARE property RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR property IN SELECT id, default_value
    FROM schema.table WHERE type_id = 3 LOOP
      if (property.default_value) IS NULL THEN
        UPDATE schema.table SET default_value = ''DEFAULT'' WHERE id = property.id;
      END IF ;
  END LOOP;
END';
```

This fails ('schema.' means some schema, such as 'public'):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION theScript(TEXT)
  RETURNS VOID AS '
DECLARE
  _table_name ALIAS FOR $1;
  _sub_id integer;
  _prop_id integer;
  _ent_id integer;
  _ent_sub_id integer;
BEGIN
  FOR _ent_id IN EXECUTE ''SELECT id FROM schema.'' || _table_name LOOP
    EXECUTE '' SELECT sub_id FROM schema.'' || _table_name || '' WHERE id = '' || _ent_id
    INTO _ent_sub_id;
    IF _ent_sub_id IS NULL THEN
      EXECUTE '' SELECT sub_property_id FROM schema.'' || _table_name || ''_data WHERE '' || _table_name || ''_id = '' || _ent_id || '' LIMIT 1''
      INTO _prop_id;
      SELECT subdivision_id
      from bms.subdivision_property
      where id = _prop_id
      INTO _sub_id;
      EXECUTE '' UPDATE schema.'' || _table_name || '' SET sub_id = '' || (_sub_id) || '' WHERE id = '' || _ent_id;
      RAISE NOTICE ''UPDATED FIELD ID: %'', _ent_id;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT theScript('terminal');
```

What is the possible cause of this?

Comment: sqlQuery.executeUpdate() is meant to be used to execute a query that does not return any results (update, delete ...), apparently one of your files has a select clause so it will return some results, use sqlQuery.getResultList() for those scripts with a select clause

Comment: @Elgayed is there a way to check somehow which one I should use, before executing a script? Because I have various scripts in files and calling void ones with getResultList() would also generate an error.

Comment: Are you aware you don't need to quote the body of a function? And do you also get the error when running from psql/pgadmin or only when running from your java code?

Comment: One way to do it is to use the 'Statement' interface instead of 'Query' inetrface. statement has an execute function that performs both data selection and records updates, statement.execute("sqlQuery")
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Elgayed I'll try... Thanks.

Comment: @eurotrash I can't use $$ because Spring which uses these scripts in another module doesn't understand them. IDE shows errors if I remove quotes.

Comment: Ok that's weird, sounds like an issue with your IDE then (the quotes, not your actual issue) cause postgres does not require quotes, in fact I didn't even know you could put the whole body in quotes, never seen it done before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## select void

In your `SELECT` statement, the `SELECT` returns one row (because no `FROM` and no `WHERE`) with one column of type void. It returns something.

```
create function is_void(p_text text) returns void
  language plpgsql as
'begin
end';

select is_void('one');
```

If you want to return nothing yo can do something like this:

```
create function is_void(p_text text) returns void
  language plpgsql as
'begin
end';

do $$
begin
  perform is_void('one');
end
$$;
```